# How to avoid duplicated objects being inserted in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, duplicates

Well, I am having problems with an nsarray that it is adding duplicate objects from an nsdictionary.

The situation is this: I have a plist file with an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary have the key being 'codigo' and 'var'.

What I did is I am checking each 'var' value if it is < 0 and if it is 'codigo' and 'var' will get a color using NSAttributedStrings.

The problem comes when I iterate through the array and add the evaluated 'var' into the new array. I am getting duplicated objects in the final array.

EDIT: Solution derived from xlc0212's answer and help through chat:

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.020 target:self
                                        selector:@selector(time:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSDictionary *redAttrs    = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
NSDictionary *greenAttrs  = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.118 green:0.506 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000]};
NSDictionary *orangeAttrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor orangeColor]};

NSString *stringUm = @"";
NSString *stringDois = @"";
NSString *stringTres = @"";


arrayAtivos = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];
NSDictionary *item = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

for (item in array){

    NSString *alfa = [item objectForKey:@"var"];

    float fltNumber = [alfa floatValue];

    if (fltNumber < 0) {
        stringUm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2f  ",[item objectForKey:@"codigo"], fltNumber];
        int strLength = [stringUm length];
        attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringUm];
        [attStr setAttributes:redAttrs range:NSMakeRange(0,strLength)];

    } else if (fltNumber > 0 ) {
        stringDois = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2f  ",[item objectForKey:@"codigo"], fltNumber];
        int strLength = [stringDois length];
        attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringDois];
        [attStr setAttributes:greenAttrs range:NSMakeRange(0,strLength)];

    } else if (fltNumber == 0) {
        stringTres = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2f  ",[item objectForKey:@"codigo"], fltNumber];
        int strLength = [stringTres length];
        attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringTres];
        [attStr setAttributes:orangeAttrs range:NSMakeRange(0,strLength)];
    }

    [arrayAtivos addObject:attStr];

}
```

Comment: Does the order of the objects in arrayAtivos matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NSMutableOrderedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you want. Just replace `NSMutableArray` with `NSMutableOrderedSet` and done.

If you want to filter the array, use this

```
NSArray *array = // your array
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray: array] mutableCopy];
```

---

Replace

```
arrayAtivos = [NSMutableArray new];
```

with this

```
arrayAtivos = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];
```

and change the type of `arrayAtivos` to `NSMutableOrderedSet`

Comment: Ok, but making that change do I have to still use the 'if' statement at the bottom of the code?

Comment: It seems that your approach is for after the creation of the array and I need the solution before.. I need to generate the array with no duplicates.

Comment: No. If the object is already in the collection, then nothing will happen. BTW, `![attStr isEqual:attStr]` always evaluate to False except `attStr` is nil.

Comment: what you want is to change the type of `arrayAtivos` to `NSMutableOrderedSet`

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me now, but I removed the 'if'statement, added  this:   filteredArray = [[[[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:arrayAtivos] array] mutableCopy];  But now it returns me nothing.

Comment: Ok, but do I need to remove the if statement?

Comment: Didn't work. I edited the code to the how it is now so that you can check it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23351/discussion-between-marco-almeida-and-xlc0212)

Comment: Finally we solved this. The correct code is on the question EDIT.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly you could just do a simple check before adding the objects into the array:

```
if (![arrayAtivos containsObject:attStr]) {
     [arrayAtivos addObject:attStr];
}
```

Comment: did the change and it returned me this error:   2013-01-24 21:26:33.298 strings[663:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x715ccd0
2013-01-24 21:26:33.298 strings[663:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x715ccd0'

Comment: make sure you are using "arrayAtivos contains" not "attStr contains"

Answer (score 3):

You could just add them all to an NSSet, which doesn't allow duplicates.

You can get an array from that, although you'll be responsible for sorting them if that is important.

Comment: I already did that without success.. As far as I know that way is to remove duplicates and what I want is prior to that, I wanna avoid the insertion of duplicate objects.